# Convert dataframe to bool based on value match in each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to convert a pandas dataframe into a boolean dataframe based on matching the values of each column to that of a selected row.

The input would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'word1': ['The', 'A', 'The', 'A'],
                   'word2': ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'],
                   'word3': ['ran', 'sat', 'sat', 'ate']})
print(df)
  word1 word2 word3
0   The   cat   ran
1     A   cat   sat
2   The   dog   sat
3     A   dog   ate
```

The solution would be able to chose a specific row and then match each value of that row to the other values in that column.
For example choosing row 0 would match "The" in column "word1", "cat" in "word2", and "ran" in "word3".

The expected result would be:

```
# match the values of row 0 to that of each column

print(df_result)
   word1  word2  word3
0   True   True   True
1  False   True  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it with apply:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'word1': ['The', 'A', 'The', 'A'], 
                   'word2': ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'], 
                   'word3': ['ran', 'sat', 'sat', 'ate']})

benchmark_row = df.loc[0] #selects first row as reference

df.apply(lambda row : row == benchmark_row, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for equality between the `df` and a single row with [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
row = 0
df_result = df.eq(df.iloc[row])
df_result

   word1  word2  word3
0   True   True   True
1  False   True  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

The equivalent of `==`:

```
row = 0
df_result = (df == df.iloc[row])
```

Use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if you want to select a row based on the index *label*, instead of its *position* ([`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc)).